# Sort pyspark data frame in descending order

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a data frame looks like -

```
id      item      sale
1        a        100
2        b        300
3        c        200
4        d        800
5        e        400
```

I want data frame sorting in descending order. My final output should -

```
id      item      sale
4        d        800
5        e        400
2        b        300
3        c        200
1        a        100
```

My code is  -

```
df = df.orderBy('sale',ascending = False)
```

But gives me wrong results.

Comment: Can you check your data type for 'sale'. The code is correct and gives correct result

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type of the column sale. It have to be Interger, Decimal or float. You can check the column types with:

`df.dtypes`

Also, you can try sorting your dataframe with:

`df = df.sort(col("sale").desc())`